# finding the max value for values the row before through the row after for each row in R

Tags: r

I have looked for an answer high and low.  It seems so simple but I am struggling with getting anything to work.

Using R 3.0 in Win 7.

I am looking for a way to find the max value (row by row) for: the row of interest, the row before, and row after.

an example would look something like this:

```
   x  max
1  1   NA
2  7    7
3  3    7
4  4    5
5  5    5
```

I could do this with a loop but I would like to avoid that if possible.  I have explored things similar to `rowSums` and `rollmean` but they do not quite fit the bill since I want a max for a row after it as well.

Any thoughts are greatly appreciated!!

Comment: If the answer for the last row is 5 why is the answer for the first now not 7?  Or if the answer for the first row is NA then why is the answer for the last row not also NA?

Comment: Shouldn't the last "5" be `NA`, too? Perhaps, you could wrap your `x` between `NA`s and check `zoo::rollapply(x, 3, max)` or `RcppRoll:roll_max(x, 3)`

Comment: you are both right.... my example really should also be NA for row 5

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use `embed` and `pmax` in base R for this.

```
d <- data.frame(x=c(1,7,3,4,5))
transform(d, max=c(NA, do.call(pmax, as.data.frame(embed(d$x, 3))), NA))
#   x max
# 1 1  NA
# 2 7   7
# 3 3   7
# 4 4   5
# 5 5  NA
```

Comment: Thanks Matt..... I am interested in the `rollapply` and the `roll_max` that alexis mentioned above but I think `pmax` is what I am looking for.  THANK YOU!!!!!

Answer (score 3):

Here's an approach using dplyr's `lead()` and `lag()` functions:

```
library(dplyr)

d <- data.frame(x = c(1,7,3,4,5))
mutate(d, max = pmax(lead(x), x, lag(x)))
#>   x max
#> 1 1  NA
#> 2 7   7
#> 3 3   7
#> 4 4   5
#> 5 5  NA
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you want to do this for a matrix, not for a vector(use rollapply for vectors), this is straightforward solution, probably not the best in terms of the speed:

```
library(Hmisc)
x <- matrix(runif(10), ncol=2)
rowMaxs  <- apply(x, 1, max)

row3Maxs <- apply(cbind(rowMaxs, 
                        Lag(rowMaxs, 1), 
                        Lag(rowMaxs, -1)), 1, max)

cbind(x, row3Maxs)
```

however from the performance standpoint the following might be better:

```
row3Maxsc <- c(NA, 
          sapply(2:(length(rowMaxs)-1), 
                 function(i)
                   max(rowMaxs[i], rowMaxs[i-1], rowMaxs[i+1])
                 ),
          NA)
cbind(x, row3Maxs)
```